# Zero Phase - Moving Average Filter

Tags: filters

How can I obtain a Zero Phase Moving Average Filter? I read for example in Matlab that filtfilt give you zero phase doing forward and backward filter, I dont understand well how that work, I think taking the same number of values in the past and future can give me that, but it isnt causal right?

Comment: That's correct: taking the same number in the past and the future will give you a zero phase filter (provided the coefficient values are (anti)symmetric), but the filter will not be causal. Does it need to be? Most offline processing does not require causality, hence `filtfilt`.

Comment: Can I obtain a zero phase without taking future values?

Comment: [Only in some esoteric situations.](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=17528&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel1%2F29%2F636%2F00017528)

Comment: boy, @PeterK., i can't imagine a truly linear-phase and causal filter that is truly IIR.  i can't see how you would get symmetry without the thing being FIR.  and, semantically, i would call a Truncated IIR (TIIR) a method of implementing a class of FIR.  and then you don't get linear phase unless you to the `filtfilt` thing with it, blockwise, sorta like Powell-Chau.

Comment: [This answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9467/what-is-the-advantage-of-matlabs-filtfilt/9468#9468) explains how `filtfilt` works.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson like I said, the Clements & Pease paper is a bit esoteric, but it shows linear phase IIR filters are possible... Just not realizable with LCCDEs.

Answer (score 3):

A zero phase moving average filter is an odd length FIR filter with coefficients

$$h[n]=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{N},&\quad -(N-1)/2\le n\le (N-1)/2\\0,&\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

where $N$ is the (odd) filter length. Since $h[n]$ has non-zero values for $n<0$, it is not causal, and consequently, it can only be implemented by adding a delay, i.e. by making it causal.

Note that you can't simply use Matlab's `filtfilt` function with that filter because even though you would get zero phase (with a delay), the magnitude of the filter's transfer function gets squared, corresponding to a triangular impulse response (i.e., input samples further away from the current sample receive less weight).

[This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9467/what-is-the-advantage-of-matlabs-filtfilt/9468#9468) explains in more detail what `filtfilt` does.

See also [this related question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13970/can-a-causal-filter-without-phase-shifts-exist?rq=1).